# Why the (dualizing) sheaf over a nodal curve is invertible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a nodal curve over a field $k$. Let $\Sigma=\{z_i\}$ be the nodes of $C$. Consider the normalization $f:\widetilde{C}\to C$ with $f^{-1}(\Sigma)=:\widetilde{\Sigma}$ and $\{p_i,q_i\}=f^{-1}(z_i)$. Let $\omega_C\subset f_*\Omega_{\widetilde{C}}(\widetilde{\Sigma})$, and all local sections are the rational sections $s$ of $\Omega_{\widetilde{C}}$ with worst simple poles along $\widetilde{\Sigma}$ such that for all $i$, $res_{p_i}(s)+res_{q_i}(s)=0$.

(a)[Has solved] For any etale morphism $g:C'\to C$, we have $g^*\omega_C\cong\omega_{C'}$;

(b) Conclude that $\omega_C$ is invertible.

How to solve (b)? I don't know how to use (a) because $C'$ always have singular points in this way.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What reference do you use?

Comment: @red_trumpet I'm using a notes written by Jarod Alper ( https://sites.math.washington.edu/~jarod/moduli.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way:

Use a corollary of Artin approximation and the structure of nodes, there exists a separable extension $K/k$ such that we get the
common étale neighborhood $F:(U,u)\rightarrow(C,p)$ and $G:(U,u)\rightarrow(D:=Spec K[x,y]/(xy),0)$. Easy to see that $\omega_D\cong\mathscr{O}_D$. Hence by (a), $\omega_U$ is a line bundle. As $F^*\omega_C=\omega_U$ be a line bundle, we use
the descent theory and we win.

Answer (score 2):

One way to see this is to verify that a nodal curve is a local complete intersection, i.e. all local rings $\mathcal O_{C,p}$ are lci. If you embed an lci variety into projective space $\mathbb P^n$, the adjunction formula holds:
$$\omega_C = \omega_{\mathbb P^n}|_C \otimes \Lambda^{n-1} N_{C/\mathbb P^n}, \tag{1}$$
where $N_{C/\mathbb P^n}$ is the normal bundle of $C$ in $\mathbb P^n$ (which is locally free as $C$ is lci). From (1) it is immediately clear that $\omega_C$ is invertible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I understand your proof. But have we used (1)?

Comment: @DiamondVillager (1) implies that $\omega_C$ is invertible. How else would you see this?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought your (1) was my (a).

Comment: But here we don’t know $\omega_C$ is the dualizing sheaf, so we may can’t use this formula. I have another solution of this as in my answer.